# Add Gem to Distributed Cache in Hive

Tags: ruby, hive, hadoop-streaming

I have a ruby script that I want to use with Hive streaming.  This script requires the use of an external gem.  Because this gem is not installed on my data nodes, the script will not run.

I would prefer to be able to add this gem on a temporary basis just to run this job.  Is there a way to include this gem to the distributed cache?  Maybe as a zip? (e.g. ADD FILE custom_gem.zip)

Comment: Perhaps this is possible using a jar or go (golang) file instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I have found to do this is to manually add the files of the gem to the distributed cache.

Here is an example of using the browser Ruby gem:

I download and unzip `browser-master.zip` from GitHub.   Then I add the entire unzipped folder to the distributed cache:

```
ADD FILE /home/user/browser-master
```

In the Ruby script that I am using in Hive, I have to tell Ruby where to find the needed files from the gem:

```
$.push File.expand_path("../browser-master/lib", __FILE__)
require "browser"
```